# Trouble using MS Access to migrate data between Oracle databases that contain blobs

Tags: database, oracle, ms-access, data-migration

Im currently trying to move data from three old database schemas into one new one.
I have been doing this using MS Access's append query function.

Everything has gone pretty smoothly until I tried to move across data that contained Blobs. Oracle returns a 'ORA-01008: not all variables bound' error. I have tracked this down to an error in the blobs as it works fine if I remove those columns from the query.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to overcome it?

Comment: You may have to write code using `GetChunk` and `AppendChunk`, which are functions you can use to manipulate binary data directly. But I'm just guessing here, as I've never done anything like this. You might also check to see if there's a way to create a view in Oracle that will CAST the data to a format that Access can deal with.

Comment: I ended up ignoring the blobs in MS Access and writing a small java program to copy across the blobs. Not the neatest solution but it got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do it on the server?

Without testing this (forgive the syntax errors)

While connected to the target schema

```
insert into tablename select from SourceSchemaName1.TableName;
insert into tablename select from SourceSchemaName2.TableName;
insert into tablename select from SourceSchemaName3.TableName;
```

http://psoug.org/reference/insert.html

Comment: The schemas are kept on separate servers. Due to the security we have in place its a lot more work then is needed. Although this would be a better choice if the schemas were accessible from each other.